# Should we negotiate with terrorists?

Tags: ethics

**Should we negotiate with terrorists?**

I'm not asking whether we should allow reformed terrorists to have a say in the running of society, but if we are morally obliged to, or indeed prohibited from, negotiating with people who are using terror to achieve their ends?

On the one hand, their demands and methods are evil. Grant me that, as I am a good judge of ethics. On the other, isn't that how wars start?

I'm interested in an answer from any mainstream ethics.

Comment: What kind of terrorists, under what moral framework? One man's terrorist is another man's freedom fighter, and there are no unconditional answers in ethics. If one is a utilitarian the answer depends on the demands, how much leverage terrorists have, how much others will be encouraged by such negotiations to repeat the deed, how difficult it is to obtain similar leverage, etc. In most cases the cost/benefit would probably go against negotiations, but if what terrorists got is particularly rare and particularly destructive then negotiations may be warranted. Or at least a pretense at them.

Comment: oh I meant to imply there are good reasons to negotiate (there is leverage) but they are not "freedom fighters" @Conifold

Comment: Hi Anon - have you been doing any particular previous ethics reading so that we might have a starting point to jump off from?

Comment: @anon But what if some people describe them as "terrorists" but other people say they are "freedom fighters"? How do you decide which is which?

Comment: are those mutually exclusive for you @tkruse they aren't for very many other people

Comment: I'm not sure philosophy would never have anything to say about it. a socio-ethical question? just because it's rarely answered, doesn't mean it shouldn't be asked @tkruse !

Answer (score 1):

The answers are as numerous as are the particular ethics people follow.  For example, in a given religion, there may be a religious edict forbidding negotiations with terrorists whose particular brand of terrorism goes against the religion.  To enumerate them all would be impossible.  However, I find the most typical arguments regarding negotiating with terrorists are from a utilitarian point of view.  This may be because utilitarianism can appeal well across many ethical positions when the person has no other reason to argue against it (e.g. religious rulings).

The utilitarian argument is one tied to the debate between minimizing any given terrorist event versus minimizing terrorism in general.  For any given event, the naive utilitarian argument is to negotiate.  Indeed, this is almost vacuous.  The terrorists would have chosen their position such that it makes sense to negotiate with them, or else there would not be a question of negotiation.

However, it is often argued that refusing to negotiate to terrorism has a utilitarian value in decreasing the value of such actions to terrorists.  There's little value in kidnapping someone to most terrorists.  Their value was in the ability to negotiate their return in exchange for currency.  If it is known that this negotiation does not take place, then there is little advantage in executing the kidnapping.

Which argument wins out depends on how you view the terrorists.  If you assume all terrorists are pure evil and intensely clever, refusing to negotiate has its perks.  It denies *any* terrorist from negotiation.  On the other hand, if you consider that there may be some larger gestalt humanity that links all of us, including the terrorists, then that suggests that there's some balance to be had between stopping the terror and minimizing the pain caused by that terror via negotiation.

So, even within a single framework (and arguably the simplest of frameworks), there are many answers.  Such is oft the case with questions like these.  Were there to be one answer, we'd be following it, and you probably wouldn't have a question about it!